# PostgreSQLи Node js

Tags: node.js, reactjs, postgresql

Я использую модуль pg в react/node web приложении для работы с postgreSQL базой. Допустим, я хочу получить какие-то данные:

**dbConfig.js**

```
const pg = require('pg');

const dbConfig = {
    user: 'postgres',
    host: 'localhost',
    database: 'myDatabase',
    password: 'myPassword',
    port: 4000
};

const pool = new pg.Pool(dbConfig);

module.exports = pool;
```

**userDAO.js**

```
const pool = require('../dbConfig);

exports.getUserList = async (request, response) => {

    let sql = 'Select * From USERS';

    try{
        const users = await pool.query(sql);

        response.send(users);
    } catch (e) {
        response.send(e);
    }
};
```

И появляется сразу много вопросов:

1. Что на счёт закрытия соединения? Этот пул будет висеть в течение всей сессии для конкретного пользователя? В JDBC каждое соединение закрывается, тут другая логика?
2. Закроется ли соединение, если пользователь покинет моё приложение или мне надо как-то это предусмотреть?
3. (Вытекает из первого) Сколько пользователей одновременно сможет сидеть в моём приложении?
4. Что такое `pool.connect()`? Читал документацию, разные примеры. Где-то используется, где-то нет, не понимаю в каких случаях он нужен
5. Когда использовать `pool.end()`?
6. Я правильно использую этот модуль? Может, кто-то сможет на этом примере показать что не так?

Прошу помогите. Спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ответы на все ваши вопросы есть в официальной [документации](https://node-postgres.com/api/pool).

Я не эксперт, но попробую ответить:

1) pool.query - запускается на первом доступном клиенте из пула, после чего сразу возвращает клиент обратно для других запросов, а вам результат запроса. Закрывать его не нужно, всё происходит автоматически.

2) pool.query работает на один запрос и не может быть применён для транзакций сам по себе, собственно если вам по какой-то причине нужно для пользователя сохранять соединение, используйте или транзакции или pool.connect для резервации клиента, но его вот уже нужно будет отпустить по завершению работ (release).

3) Это некорректный вопрос, например вы создали пул на 20 клиентов и единовременно может совершаться 20+ запросов к БД если вы используете pool.query и в зависимости от количества запросов вашего приложения в бд, столько клиентов оно и сможет держать без задержки, а при задержке просто время ответа будет дольше (до установленного в настройках лимита). Если вы будете использовать pool.connect, то тогда 20 клиентов или другое установленное число будет вашим максимумом.

4) Описал выше.

5) Когда вам больше не нужен пул клиентов.

6) Просто везде используйте pool.query, а если вам для одного клиента нужно сделать несколько запросов с возможностью отката при ошибке используйте транзакции:

```
const { Pool } = require('pg')
const pool = new Pool()
pool.connect((err, client, done) => {
  const shouldAbort = err => {
    if (err) {
      console.error('Error in transaction', err.stack)
      client.query('ROLLBACK', err => {
        if (err) {
          console.error('Error rolling back client', err.stack)
        }
        // release the client back to the pool
        done()
      })
    }
    return !!err
  }
  client.query('BEGIN', err => {
    if (shouldAbort(err)) return
    const queryText = 'INSERT INTO users(name) VALUES($1) RETURNING id'
    client.query(queryText, ['brianc'], (err, res) => {
      if (shouldAbort(err)) return
      const insertPhotoText = 'INSERT INTO photos(user_id, photo_url) VALUES ($1, $2)'
      const insertPhotoValues = [res.rows[0].id, 's3.bucket.foo']
      client.query(insertPhotoText, insertPhotoValues, (err, res) => {
        if (shouldAbort(err)) return
        client.query('COMMIT', err => {
          if (err) {
            console.error('Error committing transaction', err.stack)
          }
          done()
        })
      })
    })
  })
})
```

Comment: Я читал доки и либо не умею это делать, хотя не первый док читаю, либо там написано недостаточно понятно. Большое спасибо за подробное объяснение, очень серьёзно спасли